# ng test - Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

After deleting all `*.component.spec.ts` file in the project, ng test stopped working.

After typing ng test, these are the logs:

```
$ ng test
⠋ Generating browser application bundles...07 05 2021 16:06:36.095:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
07 05 2021 16:06:36.099:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v5.2.3 server started at http://localhost:9876/
07 05 2021 16:06:36.099:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
07 05 2021 16:06:36.102:INFO [launcher]: Starting browse✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.07 05 2021 16:06:49.628:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
07 05 2021 16:07:36.103:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
07 05 2021 16:07:36.133:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (1/2).
07 05 2021 16:08:36.134:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
07 05 2021 16:08:36.161:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (2/2).
07 05 2021 16:09:36.162:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
07 05 2021 16:09:36.189:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome failed 2 times (timeout). Giving up.
```

**Things Tried**:

- After testing with Firefox, it had the same result.
- After deleting node_modules and package-lock.json, it had the same result.

**Things to Note**:

- No test file has errors in it.
- **Project** - https://github.com/d-clone/website.git

**Versions**:

- **Chrome Version**: v90
- **@angular/core Version**: v11.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After typing `ng update`, and updating @angular/core with `ng update --force @angular/core`, tests started working again on Chrome.

This may have been an issue with the specific @angular/core version (v11.1.1), or with my Angular package versions not matching.

(I'm leaving this here to help others with same issue.)